# Django: Can signal receivers return data?

Tags: django

In Django, can signals be used as callback functions? In other words, can the "sender" of a signal use it to gather data from another app, via the return value of `send()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#sending-signals)

> Both `send()` and `send_robust()` return a list of tuple pairs `[(receiver, response), ... ]`, representing the list of called receiver functions and their response values.

Do note that this is rather a rather unorthodox mechanism for this though; if you need the return value from a function, just call it directly.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder, would it be an appropriate application for signals if you don't know the function name, or what are other alternatives.